# Ubuntu 14.04 booting, behaves like a spoiled child

Tags: boot, grub2, ati, ssd, hdmi

I've unsuccessfully tried to boot again in Ubuntu after 1 week of not using it. It clearly punishes me for that. Joke aside, please know that i'm using "vanilla"  Ubuntu. I didn't tinker with it. All i had installed is this : steam( with TF2 ), synaptic manager,gksu,a task manager, and catalyst drivers( from AMD site) All of this worked perfectly and i was able to play TF2 with frames ( experience differ form that on windows, in a negative way, but that is another topic). O wait, and UTC=no in /etc/default/rcS( cause windows clock goes haywire ).
Note also that my Ubuntu is on a separate SSD ( a Kingston, and my windows is on an OCZ, if this matters somehow.)

LE :  and also installed all the updates it notified me to do.

Also, please know, that last time i was able to boot and enjoy Ubuntu, i didn't modify anything in it, just browsing and tf2, after that i gracefully shut it down.

Now it won't boot again, and it behaves much like my other problem (https://askubuntu.com/questions/560687/ubuntu-14-04-black-screen-on-boot-on-my-pc-when-hdmi-tv-is-on). To isolate the issues I've disconnected the 
hdmi cable linking my tv to my pc.

Now i can see a dash(prompt) for a second in my uper-left corner of my screen, and after that the screen goes blank(dark) no input is possible ( numlock-light will not switch on/off) .I can only reset and the behavior repeats itself over and over again. I'm not presented with Grub menu either. I don't now how to force it.( LE: learned how, holding shift)

Important, that , sometimes, the Pc's power switch activation will bring the Ubuntu load menu( purple screen with dots in the middle) and it shuts down. But i was unable to reproduce this regularly.  Only reset button works 100% of the times.

This is not my first time  having this problem, it's my first time speaking of it, because i'm feed up  of re-installing .Which  i do from an USB-stick during boot and always a clean install. I really want to give Ubuntu a try but it feels like i'm using  a stick of dynamite out of the box. 
I have no explanation of why it worked and now it doesn't . nothing had been modified on my PC since then.

thank you, for reading this long post.
Have i nice winter.

LE :Tried boot-repair (recommended repair) ( [paste.ubuntu.com/9617705](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9617705) ) didn't worked.

LE: Tried boot-repair (advanced repair ) -> stuck in "Purge kernels then reinstall last kernel sda1 (ins) " for 45 minutes now. ( in takes 15 minutes to install the entire OS)
Will abort and do an OS clean install AGAIN!

Note to self : don't update the system when all is functional!
Case closed!

LE:
Save yourself a lot of trouble by NOT updating your system if you have everything that you need functional. In my case, I need steam to work , have decent-ish fps, browsing,no booting issues and no time to CSI ubuntu's kernel issues.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the issue with grub, so check for the grub and then update it to the latest by using command,

```
apt-get update
```

else

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have nowhere to input these commands. all i get is a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Most Ubuntu boot problems can be solved using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Boot to live session ("Try Ubuntu" option when using installation USB).
Open terminal by pressing `ctrl+alt+t`.
Type commands (press `Enter` after each line):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

Press big bad button "Recommended Repair".
???
Reboot.
Profit.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9617705/  --rebooting , finger crossed!

Comment: It didn't work! I have the same behavior. in addition , holding shift will bring grub menu so I've also tried , checking de FS,checking packages , apt-get update, upgrade,failsafex, nothing worked!

Comment: I am no guru then, but you could you post the link Boot Repair gave you to your question?

Comment: already did that! up^

Comment: I am sorry for the late answer and being blind. It would be great if you could post the link to the original question, not buried in the comments. I am guessing you did try "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and choosing earlier kernel version or recovery mode. I compared your Boot-Repair output with mine. The only meaningful difference - in my opinion - is in /etc/defalt/grub of main drives: I have HIDDEN_TIMEOUT disabled, while you have your set to 0, that means that grub menu is not shown without keypress. If you want to compare them yourself, here is my: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9077965/.

Comment: TL;DR: if you did try "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and choosing earlier kernel version or recovery mode, I am of no help.